# Javascript changing number in string

Tags: javascript, duplicates

Is there a way to loop through this code and change the numbers (i = 1,2,3) so you avoid duplication?

```
if (bool) {
    reeks1Getallen = reeks1.splice(0, k1 % (reeks1.length));
    reeks2Getallen = reeks2.splice(0, k2 % (reeks2.length));
    reeks3Getallen = reeks3.splice(0, k3 % (reeks3.length));
} else {
    reeks1Getallen = reeks1.splice(0, (reeks1.length) - k1 % reeks1.length);
    reeks2Getallen = reeks2.splice(0, (reeks2.length) - k2 % reeks2.length);
    reeks3Getallen = reeks3.splice(0, (reeks3.length) - k3 % reeks3.length);
}
reeks1 = reeks1.concat(reeks1Getallen);
reeks2 = reeks2.concat(reeks2Getallen);
reeks3 = reeks3.concat(reeks3Getallen);
```

Comment: Don't use different variable names. Use an array `var reeks = […]`

Comment: There are 3 changing strings in each statement, I won't be avoiding duplication with 1 single array, right? @Bergi

Comment: I don't see any strings in those statements at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen to what @Bergi has to say; this looks just like one of my professors' programs.

If you can't get rid of your enumerated variables right now, your code should be equivalent to:

```
for (let [reeks, k] of [[reeks1, k1], [reeks2, k2], [reeks3, k3]]) {
   const getallen = reeks.splice(0, bool ? k % reeks.length : reeks.length - k % reeks.length);
   reeks = reeks.concat(getallen);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an array of objects if you want to loop over with an index. This answer is a bit more verbose than others, but it should get the job done too:

```
var objList = [
  {
    reeks: [], // fill with your own array
    reeksGetallen: [], // fill with your own array
    k: 1
  },
  {
    reeks: [], // fill with your own array
    reeksGetallen: [], // fill with your own array
    k: 2
  },
  {
    reeks: [], // fill with your own array
    reeksGetallen: [], // fill with your own array
    k: 3
  }
];

for (var i = 0; i < objList.length; i++) { 
  var reeksGetallen = objList[i].reeksGetallen;
  var reeks = objList[i].reeks;
  var k = objList[i].k;

  if (bool) {
    reeksGetallen = reeks.splice(0, k % reeks.length);
  } else {
    reeksGetallen = reeks.splice(0, reeks.length - k % reeks.length);
  }

  reeks = reeks.concat(reeksGetallen);
}
```